# Delete <dict>...</dict> from *.plist file iPhone script

Tags: ios, bash, plist

I would like to write a script that delete one specified `dict` from *.plist file, but nothing that I found on the internet doesn't work.. Is there a way to do that ? I've tried `sed` comman but this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the plist file into a `NSDictionary`. [[Docs]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile%3a)
2. Make a `mutableCopy` of this to get a dictionary you can work with.
3. Remove the item you wish to remove
4. Write the dictionary back to disk. [[Docs]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a)

Answer (score -1):

Sed is a very bad tool for this. Try PlistBuddy instead, if it exists on iOS (it does exist on MacOS...); it's called as /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy, and allows you to manipulate plist files.

Syntax is a bit strange, but "Entries" seem to be addressed like this: you start at the top of the plist file; if it's an array then you specify the index of the element that you want to address, if it's a dictionary then you specify the key name that you want to go to. Separate such specifications by colons. Put "" around the whole thing if there are spaces.

My sample file is this:

```
stieber@:~> cat foo.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>Sample 1</key>
      <array>
        <string>Sample String 1</string>
        <dict>
          <key>Sample 2</key>
          <string>Sample String 2</string>
        </dict>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

A sample session:

```
stieber@:~> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy foo.plist
Command: print
Array {
    Dict {
        Sample 1 = Array {
            Sample String 1
            Dict {
                Sample 2 = Sample String 2
            }
        }
    }
}

Command: print "0:Sample 1:1"
Dict {
    Sample 2 = Sample String 2
}

Command: delete "0:Sample 1:1"
Command: print
Array {
    Dict {
        Sample 1 = Array {
            Sample String 1
        }
    }
}
```

You can provide commands on the command line as well, or via here documents. Interactive is just easier to play around with :-)

Comment: plist buddy is not available on iOS